# Mathematical / Scientific Symbols for Min Max

Tags: math, max, min, symbols

What are the accurate mathematical or scientific symbols to represent MIN and MAX? Thank you

Comment: max() and min() are the appropriate symbols

Comment: Look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40861/mathematical-notation-for-the-maximum-of-a-set-of-function-values) in a sister Stack Exchange site. Don't forget to read the comments, which have the best answers (in my opinion).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this:
max(f(x))=k

Comment: Thank you Arkadiusz